# angular c# update multiple ienumerable models

Tags: c#, angular, ienumerable

I think I am just having a hard time getting my head around understanding how to do this in angular/C# it's really holding my project up.

I have two database tables group_info and shop_info. When a user creates a new entry I need it to send an insert to both tables in one step (one form) but it needs to get the id field from one table and put it into the other. Group_id then goes into the shop_info table under group_id.

I'm using a reactive Angular form which then sends the full json model via the angular typescript file to the angular _services.

```
this.gpService.add(this.model).subscribe(
    (next) => {
console.log(this.model);
});
```

The service then sends the model to the C# Repository via the C# Interface which passes the information to the C# Controller. Database entry gets created all great.

Which works ok. But now what? The problem is that I also want the shop_info database entry next (which I can do from the controller) but doesn't want to use the newly created (auto incremented) group_id from group_info. If I try to make a new service call back from the angular typescript file after or inside the (next) above then it doesn't use the newly created AI group_id field.

I believe my problem is that I just don't properly understand how to update multiple models using this coding language and would appreciate any help or direction googling the right terms or examples to work through myself.

Thank you for your time reading

Comment: This does not sound like a good design. You are joggling 20 dishes at once. I would suggest you to first create on the server or even better, console program all necessary functions with a repository pattern. Simply all actions to db should be sitting inside some class. Then you solve all your methods and provide them for cosumption to other components, technologies. This way you will be capable to ask better and more specific questions. And you gona get an answer with higher probability...

Comment: are you asking how to propagate to Angular client new IDs generated server side?

Comment: hey guys sorry I am bad at wording this problem. I have a new entry from the user which will create a group and a shop at the same time. I want to store the group_id in the shop table but I cannot see how to do this in one go? I am happy to go through some examples of similar design.

Comment: @ipavlu I cannot understand when you say server what file is this? but I think what you say is that the repository is what is used to call to multiple models?

Comment: I think what you are asking is pretty normal in terms of spec. You want to insert a record into your DB that causes a cascade insert to related tables. Is that it? If so Entity Framework supports it (as you probably know). As far as returning a model to Angular, well you could create a DTO class with any data you like. Perhaps you could elaborate what isn't working?